# PHPMailer won't work with Yahoo Mail addresses (issues with $mail->AddCC method)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm a bit confused about PHPMailer. I'm trying to use it in a site, in which a person fills out a form, and includes their name, email information.

I'm trying to have that information emailed both to me, and a copy to that person - hence the usage of `$mail->addCC($email)` method.

However, every time I try to send a test email from a yahoo email address, it doesn't work. It does work with gmail address.

EDIT - when I say it doesn't work with yahoo email addresses, what I get, technically-wise, is a "mail delivery failed" email from them.

My purpose in having `$mail->addCC($email)` method is so that a copy is sent to the user, and the one that's sent to me is that one that I can respond back to.

I've tried `$mail->addCustomHeader($email);` but that still creates the same problem, ie, yahoo mail won't deliver it.

How do I make this PHPMailer work so a copy is sent to me, and to the user?

Also, am I using this PHPMailer form wrongly? I'm confused about `$mail->From = $email;` I've currently set it to be from the user's email address, so that way I can respond to it. Is that wrong?

```
$first_name = $_POST['first-name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last-name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = nl2br($_POST['message']);

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                        // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'host info';              // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                 // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user info';          // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'pw';                 // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';              // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587; 

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $first_name;
$mail->addAddress('my email address');  // Add a recipient  
$mail->addCC($email);                   // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);                    // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Hotel Room Request';
$mail->Body    = $message; 

$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    header('location: url here');
} else {
    header('location: url here');
}
```

Comment: Check your spam filter? Receive any errors from PHP?

Comment: @Sam, No need to check spam filter. I receive "Mail delivery failed" message from yahoo every single time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the From as originating from the sender (in this case Yahoo, but other ISPs will also block) is your problem. The receiving mail server can quickly identify that it has not sent the message - and once it does, it suspects spam.

Instead, set From to some address on your server (no-reply@ is what I typically use) and then add the sender as Reply-To header.

Reply-To header does exactly what it sounds like: when you click the "Reply" button, it populates a new message sending to that value *instead* of the actual sender.

```
$mail->addReplyTo( $email, $first_name );
$mail->addAddress( $email, $first_name );
$mail->addAddress( 'your@email.com', 'You' );
$mail->From = 'your@email.com';
$mail->FromName = $first_name;
```

In response to your later comment, about the Reply-To being the own user's address, I would handle like so:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                        // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'host info';              // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                 // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user info';          // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'pw';                 // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';              // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587; 

$mail->From = 'your@email.com';
$mail->FromName = $first_name;

$mail->isHTML(true);                    // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Hotel Room Request';
$mail->Body    = $message; 

$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

// SEND TO YOURSELF

$mail->addReplyTo( $email, $first_name );
$mail->addAddress( 'your@email.com', 'You' );
$mail->send();

// CLEAR REPLY TO AND RECIPIENTS 

$mail->clearReplyTos();
$mail->clearAllRecipients();

// SEND TO THE USER

$mail->addAddress( $email, $first_name );
$mail->addReplyTo( 'your@email.com', 'You' );


if(!$mail->send()) {
    header('location: url here');
} else {
    header('location: url here');
}
```

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: @Set Sail Media, hey, thanks! Appreciate it. A question though, if you don't mind. When I tested this, and checked the reply-to from my email address, it was populated with the user's address (yay!), but when I checked from the "user" email, and hit reply-to, it was to the user's email address, and not to mine. How do I adjust this?

Comment: I'll update my answer to show a better way to handle this - basically what I would do is send the message once, to yourself, clear the recipient and clear the replyto, add back in, send to the user.